# Where is the implementation of Display trait for &str

Tags: string, rust, traits, display

I know that str implements the trait Display. However, It is said that &str also implements this trait.

I wanna inspect the implementation detail of Display trait for &str, but I searched the resource code base of Rust and didn't find it. It doesn't exist in the std::str or the std::fmt::Display crates.

Maybe I had miss something I didn't realize. Can anyone give me some clue about where to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `str` implements `Display`, i.e.: [`impl Display for str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#impl-Display).

Second, there is a *blanket implementation* that implements `Display` for every reference type whose referent type also implements `Display`, i.e., [`impl<'_, T> Display for &'_ T where T: Display + ?Sized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html#impl-Display-86)

Therefore, `&str` implements `Display` because its referent type, `str`, also does.

Answer (score 0):

It is not implemented directly for `&str`. Rather, [there is a blanket implementation `impl<T: ?Sized + Display> Display for &'_ T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.62.1/src/core/fmt/mod.rs.html#2129-2144).